# How Can I Create Datatable Form Firestore to CSV file in Flutter

Tags: firebase, csv, flutter, pdf, google-cloud-firestore

**OK, here is the story :**

My app can create reports, now these reports are displayed neatly in a table. The data is being streamed from firestore.

**The problem:**

There is a must-have feature of being able to export the report out of the app, like emailing it. So I tried exporting it to PDF, but it only saves what is currently viewed in the scaffold, meaning the rows and columns that needs a scroll to be shown/seen aren't exported to the PDF. Currently I'm trying to do the same but to the CSV file that contains all the data streamed from the firestore instance, formatting it in a data-table view

**editted with the full code **
**And here is the code:**

```
  import 'dart:io';

import 'package:basic_utils/basic_utils.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:csv/csv.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:flutter_email_sender/flutter_email_sender.dart';

class AdminPage extends StatefulWidget {
  static final TextEditingController _emailController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  _AdminPageState createState() => _AdminPageState();
}

class _AdminPageState extends State<AdminPage> {
  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formkey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  DocumentSnapshot _currentDocument;

  String filePath;
  String currentProcess;
  bool isProcessing = false;

  Future<String> get _localPath async {
    final directory = await getApplicationSupportDirectory();

    return directory.absolute.path;
  }

  Future<File> get _localFile async {
    final path = await _localPath;
    filePath = '$path/clouddata.csv';
    return File('$path/clouddata.csv').create();
  }



  List<List<dynamic>> rows = List<List<dynamic>>();
  getCsv(DocumentSnapshot document) async {
    setState(() {
      currentProcess = "Getting data from the cloud";
      isProcessing = true;
    });
    Firestore.instance
          .collection('Airline_Transactions').document(_currentDocument.documentID)
          .snapshots();
   {
      setState(() {
        currentProcess = "Decoding data";
      });
    }
    rows.add([
      "Date",
      "Airline",
      "Flight Number",
      "Terminal",
      "pax",
      "Infant",
      "Transit",
    ]);
    if (document.data != null) {
      for (int i = 0; i < document.data.length; i++) {
        List<dynamic> row = List<dynamic>();
        row.add(document.data[i]["date"].toString());
        row.add(document.data[i]["airline"].toString());
        row.add(document.data[i]["flight_number"].toString());
        row.add(document.data[i]["terminal"].toString());
        row.add(document.data[i]["pax"].toString());
        row.add(document.data[i]["infant"].toString());
        row.add(document.data[i]["transit"].toString());
        rows.add(row);
      }


      File f = await _localFile.whenComplete(() {
        setState(() {
          currentProcess = "Writing to CSV";
        });
      });
      String csv = const ListToCsvConverter().convert(rows);
      f.writeAsString(csv);
       filePath = f.uri.path;
    }
  }

  sendMailAndAttachment() async {
    final Email email = Email(
      body:
      'Data Collected and Compiled by the Datum App. <br> A CSV file is attached to this <b>mail</b> <hr><br> Compiled at ${DateTime.now()}',
      subject: 'Datum Entry for ${DateTime.now().toString()}',
      recipients: [AdminPage._emailController.text],
      isHTML: true,
      attachmentPath: filePath,
    );

    await FlutterEmailSender.send(email);
  }

  GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Datum Dash")),
      body: ListView(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 45, right: 10, left: 10, bottom: 20),
        children: <Widget>[
          Text("Welcome to DashBoard",
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500)),
          Form(
            key: _formkey,
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
                  child: TextFormField(
                    controller: AdminPage._emailController,
                    validator: (str) => (str.length == 0)
                        ? "please enter your email"
                        : (!EmailUtils.isEmail(str))
                        ? "please enter a valid email"
                        : null,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        labelText: "Enter your email",
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        suffixIcon: Icon(Icons.email)),
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0),
                  child: RaisedButton(
                    color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                    child: Text("Compile and Send"),
                    onPressed: (isProcessing)
                        ? null
                        : () async {
                      if (_formkey.currentState.validate()) {
                        try {
                          final result =
                          await InternetAddress.lookup('google.com');
                          if (result.isNotEmpty &&
                              result[0].rawAddress.isNotEmpty) {
                            await getCsv(_currentDocument).then((v) {
                              setState(() {
                                currentProcess =
                                "Compiling and sending mail";
                              });
                              sendMailAndAttachment().whenComplete(() {
                                setState(() {
                                  isProcessing = false;
                                });
                                _scaffoldKey.currentState
                                    .showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                                  content: Text("Data Sent"),
                                ));
                              });
                            });
                          }
                        } on SocketException catch (_) {
                          _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                            content: Text(
                                "Connect your device to the internet, and try again"),
                          ));
                        }
                      }
                    },
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Visibility(
                    visible: (isProcessing) ? true : false,
                    child: Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        SizedBox(
                            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                            height: 25,
                            width: 25),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                          child: Text("$currentProcess"),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: To move this forward, are you receiving an error? What happens?

Comment: no error, but am not receiving any data from the firestore

Comment: the code just stuck on  currentProcess = "Getting data from the cloud";

Comment: the ui just keep saying 'Getting data from the cloud' forever. i will edit the post with the full code

Comment: Does this issue still persist? I couldn't find a common issue that describes your scenario. I'm thinking this is an issue with the configuration of your project.

Comment: i have found a way to fix it thanks

Comment: @Rex Hey I want something similar, I want to get data from firestore and convert it to fav and give it to user but I want it to do both on mobile app and flutter web also, is it possible to do on web? Or is there any other method? And how did you solve your problem?